# Emacs (24) loads and runs emacs-w3m, but doesn't use it for Lisp HyperSpec

Tags: emacs, slime, emacs24, w3m

I'm running an Emacs 24 + SLIME set up currently and am trying to get the Common Lisp HyperSpec to display in Emacs via emacs-w3m. Presently, if I enter into the mini-buffer
`M-x w3m` it does indeed fire up emacs-w3m, and all works as expected.

However, the issue comes when in SLIME mode and attempting to load the HyperSpec via w3m. I have a local copy of the document on hand, and have it set up as my common-lisp-hyperspec-root in my `~/.emcas` file. The issue comes in when I `C-c C-d h` into the mini-buffer and attempt to search the HyperSpec. It works, but instead of using w3m in emacs it pulls up a new tab in my normal web browser (in this case Firefox) Looking at the README for the utility, it says to make sure to have `(require 'w3m-load)` in ones `~/.emcas` file, and I have done that. There are no start up errors for Emacs either, for that matter.

Is their any way for me to force Emacs to use w3m to open local documents, or failing that, to make it NOT use any other possible web browser?

My  full `~/.emcas` file is here: http://pastebin.com/E51upqF4

Edit: As an update, it is worth note that if I uninstall Firefox and try the same again, it simply opens another emacs buffer with the html itself. Still, it does not use w3m.

Comment: Maybe try to put the `(require 'w3m-load)` before the other things.

Comment: @Dualinity Moving around the require doesn't seem to affect anything. And wvxvw, after adding setting that it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to my .emacs and it works

(setq browse-url-browser-function 'w3m-goto-url)

I had no need to use:

(require 'w3m-load)